# Создание 5 классов для 1 темы ООП

Tags: c++, ооп

Приветствую. Есть тема - Справочник владельца видеотеки.

База видеофильмов: название, студия, жанр, год выпуска, режиссер, исполнители главных ролей, краткое содержание, субъективная оценка фильма. Факт присутствия фильма в видеотеке. Оформление выдачи и возвращения кассеты (это и задание уже).

Как реализовать 5 классов по этой теме (на С++, ООП)?

ООП начал изучать и уже работал с классами, наследованием, конструкторами и т.д., но вот саму логику чтобы создать именно 5 классов с виртуальным наследованием, которые будут взаимодействовать сами с собой - это пока сложно для меня.

**Не нужно кода**, помогите пожалуйста советом о реализации этих 5 классов.

Comment: Советую: начините с одного!

Comment: Нужномк именно 5. Один класс будет отвечать за данные, своеобразная база данных, другие же будут наследовать его поля и методы.

Comment: Вот и начните с одного, с предка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно тут имеется в виду использование чисто виртуального класса фильм,а от него реализовать 4 класса наследника? 
Как вариант,класс фильм,чисто виртуальный и содержит в себе лишь методы(чисто виртуальный деструктор),а классы наследники уже имеют поля и оверрайд методы.
Ты таким методом и полиморфизм покажешь создавая объекты через указатель типа фильм,а так же и классов наплодишь.

Comment: Это хорошая идея, но я не могу придумать этих наследников.

Comment: Фильм - родительский,наследники: хоррор,комедия,фентези,детектив.

Answer (score 2):

По хорошему, тут не особо нужно наследование - разве что все фильмы могут наследоваться от одного базового класса "фильм" для того, что бы можно было хранить фильмы в массиве (лучше использовать для этого `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Film>>` для того, чтобы избежать проблем с удалением объектов, но для лаб это может быть лишним). От фильма можно унаследовать несколько классов по жанрам, но различаться они будут только значением поля "жанр", на практике так делать - плохая идея. Но, видимо, от вас требуют именно этого.

Возможно, пройдет такая идея: в базовом классе Film объявить виртуальный метод `std::string getDescription()` (вернуть описание), а в потомках реализовать разный формат возвращаемого значения в зависимости от жанра (поменять местами порядок вывода полей, например).

Куда впихнуть виртуальное наследование - я даже не представляю. Его вообще не рекомендуется использовать.